# JSON parse error: unexpected identifier "undefined" for multiple HTTP requests in window.onload()

Tags: javascript, html, http

I'm making a get request and displaying it on the page however I keep getting this error for jsondataComp variables.

When I used 2 different HTTP objects I used to get the same error with internal server error so im just using 1 http object now.

Any suggestions on refactoring welcome. thanks

```
window.onload = function(){

  url='http://127.0.0.1:5000//company/lines/'+localStorage.getItem("ponumber");
  url2='http://127.0.0.1:5000//company/qty/'+localStorage.getItem("ponumber")

var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Http.send();

var dataComp;
var jsondataComp;
var dataComp2;
var jsondataComp2;

Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
   dataComp =Http.responseText;
}

//http request to get parts available for each part in each line:

Http.open("GET", url2);
Http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Http.send();

Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  dataComp2 =Http.responseText;
}


  jsondataComp = JSON.parse(dataComp);
  jsondataComp2 = JSON.parse(dataComp2);

  var table = document.getElementById('table1');
  var count = 0;
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    jsondataComp.forEach(function(object) {
   
    count++;
    tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + count + '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + object.poNo_002 + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + object.lineNo_002+ '</td>'+
    '<td>' + object.linePrice_002 + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + object.partNo_002 + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + object.linesQty_002 + '</td>'

  });


  //function display available quantity of each part in lines

  jsondataComp2.forEach(function(object) {
    tr.innerHTML+= '<td>' + object.qty_002 + '</td>' 

 });

  table.appendChild(tr);
```

}

Comment: The problem here is that you have used the two variables "dataComp" and "dataComp2" before the values are assigned. Although you have already defined the variables, the values are assigned after the HTTP request returns a response. But since you are getting the data without an asynchronous function, the rest of the code runs regardless of the response that is coming from the HTTP request. By the time you response is available the JSON.parse(dataComp) line is already executed. Try using asynchronous function for the data fetch and assign the response to your variable. Then it will work well.

Comment: thanks, apparently it had more to with window.onload. Separate functions with async works